# Prevent browser from opening applications

Tags: android, android-intent, soundcloud, intentfilter

I'm using soundcloud api and I'm trying to generate an access token from their OAuth2 authorization endpoint which is https://soundcloud.com/connect.

In the authentication process, I fire up an Intent to launch the default browser and go to the link specified above. The problem is, it automatically opens soundcloud's native app and shows a toast "There was a problem loading that URL" because the sc native app is set to open m.soundcloud.com and soundcloud.com URLs.

However, when I open the browser myself and enter the address manually, It works just fine without opening the sc native app. It is notable to mention that there exists an app on the store that opens the connect link above in the default browser without the native sc app popping up.

I was wondering if there is an intent filter or something to force the browser not to redirect to any 3rd party apps or to act as if I opened it manually without an Intent. I don't know if this makes any sense, but I hope you got the idea.